# Visual Studio 2017 help not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 community. If I hit F1 anywhere in the IDE text editor nothing happens. What I really want is to highlight a method name or property, hit F1 and be taken to the online help page for that keyword, if its part of .Net.

How do I enable this? I cannot seem to find the setting to make this work, but to be honest this should be configured out of the box, right?

Ta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It should be configured out of the box with F1 open Help page. Have you installed extensions like Resharper or other big Powerful tools? Then it could be overwritten.

Look in Tools-> Options->Enviroment-> KeyBoard and search for "Help.F1Help" there you see the Shortcut for Help

Comment: Spot on! Tools-> Options->Enviroment-> KeyBoard->"Help.F1Help" had no shortcut key mapped to it.

I dont recall installing one of the tools, but you never know. Thanks bud. Great answer.